# JavaScript append Key:Value Pair to Hash

Tags: javascript, hash

I have the below hash key:value pair defined in JavaScript. What is the most efficient way of appending the below values onto the end of the Hash:

```
Title: 'Title5', Description: 'Description5', Status: 'Status5', Complete: 'Complete5'
```

Code:

```
data = {
    d : {
        results: [
            { Title: 'Title1', Description: 'Description1', Status: 'Status1', Complete: 'Complete1' },
            { Title: 'Title2', Description: 'Description2', Status: 'Status2', Complete: 'Complete2' },
            { Title: 'Title3', Description: 'Description3', Status: 'Status3', Complete: 'Complete3' },
            { Title: 'Title4', Description: 'Description4', Status: 'Status4', Complete: 'Complete4' }
        ]
    }
};
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you never done this before?

Comment: What terms of efficiency are you talking? CPU Performance? Dev Performance? Does it matter that much for the task at hand?

Comment: But what is that first line of code? A string? An object? If object - `data.d.results.push(yourObj)`.

Comment: Yes i'm fairly new to JavaScript. No it doesn't matter regarding performance.data.d.results.push(Title: 'Title5', Description: 'Description5', Status: 'Status5', Complete: 'Complete5'); doesn't work

Comment: never heard of dictionaries in javascript? this is not python!

Comment: It has to be an object. Just drop your first line code inside curly braces `{}` and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [`push`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp).

```
var newItem = {Title: 'Title5', Description: 'Description5', Status: 'Status5', Complete: 'Complete5'}
data.d.results.push(newItem)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data.d.results.push({Title: 'Title5', Description: 'Description5', Status: 'Status5', Complete: 'Complete5'});
```